# Subtract vector from 3d array

Tags: matlab

Say if I have a 3d array:

```
lat = 45:49;
lon = -116:-110;
b = rand(5,7,12);
```

where the first dimension represents the latitude, the second dimension represents the longitude and the third row represents the data. I aim to plot this 3d data on a map using the mapping toolbox. But, before doing this, I would like to find the difference between the data in 'b' and the following vector:

```
vals = [2.3,5,6.8,5.4,3.3,12,1.5,4.6,9.8,82,3.3,1];
```

Specifically, for each spatial data point that I have in my mapped data I owuld like to calculate the mean absolute error between that vector and the data at each point in b. If these were two normal vectors I would use:

```
mae = mean(abs(bv - vals))
```

but I'm not sure how this can be done with the 3d array. Eventually, I aim to map this mean absolute error to see how it varies spatially. Can anyone suggest how this can be done in matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bsxfun` for this (it's more efficient than `repmat`):

```
V = permute(vals, [1,3,2])  %// Make sure that the dimesions 'align' correctly. i.e. 12 elements must go in the thrid dimension to match b
mae = mean(abs(bsxfun(@minus, b, V)),3)
```

Answer (score 0):

As MATLAB does not support [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), you need to create a matrix the same size as `b` with the repeated values of `vals`. To be able to do that, first you need to change `vals` to a shape of `1x1x12` and then repeat it `5x7` times. You can do that with

```
values=repmat(permute(vals,[1 3 2]),[5 7 1]);
```

now you can

```
mae = mean(abs(bv - values))
```

Comment: `bsxfun` is a more efficient method of achieving broadcasting in Matlab: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/

Comment: @Dan It definitely is! I am just not used to it, and I was expecting Divakar would answer that :P